# Creating Dojo Build Layer from Bootstrap Files, Preferably without Exporting the Entire Dojo Library

Tags: javascript, optimization, dojo, amd, dojo-build

I have a simple Dojo 1.8 AMD web app. It has a couple of bootstrap files for different MVC views, and 3 custom modules. I want to build the two bootstrap files to include their relative dependencies.

File structure

```
- js
    - tournament_organiser
        - Alert
            - templates
                - Alert.html
        - ImportDialog
            - templates
                - ImportDialog.html 
        - SquadronPicker
            - templates
                - SquadronPicker.html           
        - Alert.js // module    
        - config.js // Dojo config file     
        - form_run.js // bootstrap for "from" view
        - list_run.js // bootstrap for "list" list          
        - package.json
        - ImportDialog.js // module
        - SquadronPicker.js // module
        - tournament_organiser.profile.js
    - dojo_toolkit
        - dojo
        - dijit
        - dojox
```

I want to build 2 layer files, one for each bootstrap. Each contains several Dijit requires for declarative widgets in the view, plus `form_run.js` uses the custom modules.

So far, I have this for `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "tournament_organiser",
    "description": "Tournament organiser app for X-Wing Miniatures Game",
    "version": "0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "dojo": "~1.8.5",
        "dijit": "~1.8.5",
        "dojox": "~1.8.5"
    },
    "main": "src",
    "homepage": "http://xwing-builder.co.uk/tournament",
    "dojoBuild": "tournament_organiser.profile.js"
}
```

And this for `tournament_organiser.profile.js`:

```
var profile = (function(){
    return {
        resourceTags: {
            // tag all.js files as modules
            amd: function(filename, mid) {
                return /\.js$/.test(filename);
            }
        },

        basePath: "./",
        releaseDir: "../tournament_organiser_built",
        action: "release",

        packages:[{
            name: "dojo",
            location: "../dojo_toolkit/dojo"
        },{
            name: "dijit",
            location: "../dojo_toolkit/dijit"
        },{
            name: "dojox",
            location: "../dojo_toolkit/dojox"
        },{
            name: "squad_builder",
            location: "../squad_builder"
        }],

        // this is the bit I'm stuck on... how do I define layers for each bootstrap?
        layers: {
            "form_run": {},
            "list_run": {}
        }

    };
})();
```

An example bootstrap file (`form_run.js`):

```
require( [ 'dojo/parser',

    'dojo/on',
    'dijit/registry',
    'dojo/dom',
    'dojo/dom-style',
    'dojo/_base/array',
    'dojo/_base/lang',
    'dojo/aspect',
    'squad_builder/loadingPane',

    'tournament_organiser/SquadronPicker',
    'tournament_organiser/Alert',

    // used by declarative dijits on page
    'dijit/form/Button',
    'dijit/form/Form',
    'dijit/form/ValidationTextBox',
    'dijit/form/DateTextBox',
    'dijit/form/NumberSpinner',
    'dijit/form/CheckBox',
    'dijit/form/Select',
    'dijit/form/FilteringSelect',

    'dojo/domReady!' ],
    function ( parser, on, registry, dom, domStyle, array, lang, aspect, loadingPane, SquadronPicker, alert )
    {
            ...
    } );
```

How do I tell the build tool to read my bootstraps to find the necessary dependencies, and bundle them all up into a single file?

Also, is it possible to output just the built layers without copying over all of the Dojo Toolkit? In production, I use the Google CDN-hosted Dojo, so would only need my layer to be included on the page.

In fact, I would prefer to just put the built layers into the same folder as the source and then load the layers in production and the original files in development. Is this a bad idea?

Edit:

I tried:

```
layers: {
    "form_run": { include: [ "tournament_organiser/form_run" ] },
    "list_run": { include: [ "tournament_organiser/list_run" ] }
}
```

But got a lot of warnings and an error: http://pastebin.com/Yqz5zhT1